# twitteR R Package OAuth issue: Error in registerTwitterOAuth(cred) : oauth argument must be of class OAuth

Tags: r, twitter, oauth

```
twitteR R Package OAuth issue: Error in registerTwitterOAuth(cred) :    
oauth argument must be of class OAuth
```

This is the code I am using in R to load in the Authentication once I have authenticated the first time.

I keep getting the error:

```
Error in registerTwitterOAuth(cred) : oauth argument must be of class OAuth
```

from the following code:

```
download.file(url="http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem", destfile="/xxx/xxx/xxx/cacert.pem")

# to get your consumerKey and consumerSecret see the twitteR documentation for instructions
cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey='xxxxxxxxx',
                         consumerSecret='xxxxxxxxx',
                         requestURL= NOTE UNABLE TO POST LINKS IN THE POST
                         accessURL = NOTE UNABLE TO POST LINKS IN THE POST
                         authURL= NOTE UNABLE TO POST LINKS IN THE POST)

# necessary step for Windows / Mac
cred$handshake(cainfo="/xxx/xxx/xxx/cacert.pem")

# save for later use for Windows / Mac
save(cred, file="/xxx/xxx/xxx/twitter authentication.Rdata")
cred <- load("/xxx/xxx/xx/twitter authentication.Rdata")
registerTwitterOAuth(cred)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
load("/xxx/xxx/xx/twitter authentication.Rdata")
```

Instead of:

```
cred <- load("/xxx/xxx/xx/twitter authentication.Rdata")
```

Comment: Also worth noting - as of recent versions of twitteR the initial process is simplified with 'cred = getTwitterOAuth(YOURKEY, YOURSECRET)'